# Altering profile of user in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration, alter

I  have an oracle DB user in DBA_USERS table whose password is expiring in some future date.
I want to change the Profile of the user to the one which has non-expiring password.

If I Alter the profile of the user to the non expiring one, does the expiry date which was there in the DBA_USERS table for this user previously before altering the profile have any effect ?
Should i update the value in the expiry date column in DBA_USERS also to null.

Comment: try to change    alter profile profile_name limit PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME unlimited;
 alter profile  profile_name limit PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME  unlimited; After the profile is updated go to the dba_user table and check the EXPIRY_DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever password expiration date is created in the oracle for any user, it will not changed if you change the profile of the user.

Password expiration date is updated when you change the password of the user and new password expiration date is set according to the profile assigned to the user.

So you must have to perform following steps in order.

1. Assign the profile with non expiring password to the user.
2. Change the password of the user.(same or different password according to your requirement)

Then next password expiration date is changed according to new profile and that will be null/non expiring/unlimited

Comment: In that case can i set the password using alter command and give the same password as previous password.. will it allow to reset with the same password.. how to change the password to same password again

Comment: "how to change the password to same password again" .... just like you did the first time.  As long as you are not violating PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME and PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX

Comment: how to bypass PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME and apply  same password?